# How to turn camera smoothly on Google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am following road directions with Street View. When I make a turning on the road I need somehow to turn camera smoothly in Street View that it would be heading road direction.

I use this:

```
panorama.setPov({pitch: 0, heading: newComputedHeading});
```

where panorama is google.maps.StreetViewPanorama object.

The problem is that it just jumps 20 or 10 or etc degrees in one go. What I want is a smooth Camera turn from old heading value to a new heading value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Break the rotation into smaller rotations, use setTimeout to schedule updates to the POV

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I am not sure how setTimeout actually works. I am using it more than once in a program and it gives me not wanted result. @geocodezip maybe you know decent tutorial about setTimeout?

Comment: Just google it (javascript setTimeout).  [This](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) has an example.